# What is more stable, efficient and powerful to use, 1.7 or the latest (1.9?)

Tags: magento-1, version

I was wondering as far as Magento versions go which is the best to use? I was having a discussion about it and how good it is and it came up in conversation that Magento 1.7 is the best to use, over the latest version (I think it's 1.9).

I'm new to Magento and was wondering, from a professionals stand point, which is the most powerful, stable and efficient to use? This isn't to settle anything, I'm curious to just see what other Magento shop owners/developers have to say on this subject.

I don't so much want this to be a poll, I'm more asking is 1.7 better than the current release or not. Are there actually any flaws (bugs) security wise present? Thanks.

Comment: Personally I can not see any reason to use an older version over the newest release.

Answer (score 1):

user21148,magento 1.9 is best to use because of `this version` is over come `to fixed issue of magento 1.7`.

Lot of new feature is include in magento  1.9 and lot bugs has been fixed here.

Please see at [Magento Ecommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes)